# Jquery - Draggable Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jquery draggable functionality on my website.

My requirement is when I drag and drop the li into a container the div has to be replaced 
with 2 text boxes.

I have been able to get that part. But on dropping a li element also gets created in the container. I want to remove this li element from the container.

The code for doing this is as given below:

```
$(".wp_addinput").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#drag_div",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var len = $('#drag_div .wp_addinput.ui-draggable').length;
        len = parseInt(len);
        if (len > 0) {
            $('#wp_dropdiv .wp_addinput.ui-draggable').remove(); // Using this I remove the li element
        }
        $(".wp_dropinput").append("add new html element");
        k++;
    },
});
```

But  I get this error on execution of remove().
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChild' of null.

Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Comment: have you tried `$(ui.draggable).remove()`

Comment: @chiliNUT: I added the line in stop event but it did not work for me

Comment: @chiliNUT:  Got it working, using the method provided by you.. but used a droppable and drop event rather than a draggable's stop event to get it working.. Thank you